# Why is AsyncTask not garbage collected if reference is out of scope?

Tags: android, multithreading, android-asynctask, garbage-collection

I am loading few images in a ListView using AsyncTask. It looks something like that:

```
private void loadImageInBackground(ViewHolder holder, Location location) {
    ImageViewLoader coverImageLoader = new ImageViewLoader(holder.locationImage, coversImgCache);
    coverImageLoader.execute(location.getImageUrl());
}
```

Where ImageViewLoader is just an extended AsyncTask.

From what I understand, garbage collector collects everything that is not referenced anymore.

As the stack pointer leaves the function above, the class loses any references on the created ImageViewLoader object. This should be then garbage collected, shouldn't it?

However, the AsyncTask still working and eventually callbacks on `onPostExecute`.

One of my guesses is that it creates a thread and that thread has a reference to the object. As soon as the thread dies, the AsyncTask is also garbage collected.

Is my guess any close to the actual answer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> One of my guesses is that it creates a thread and that thread has a reference to the object. As soon as the thread dies, the AsyncTask is also garbage collected.

That would be correct. A Thread [is considered a GC root](http://javabook.compuware.com/content/memory/how-garbage-collection-works.aspx). This thread has a reference to the `AsyncTask`, preventing it from being collected.

Still, if it should have been collected, you could not rely on the garbage collector even kicking in before `onPostExecute` is called.

Answer (score 1):

AsyncTask is just a wrapper around a java worker thread. So, while your main process is alive, your worker thread will be running and not GC. When it finishes, AsyncTask executes `onPostExecute()` on the main thread what means the worker thread is dead and the AsyncTask can be collected as a normal object.